# Bathroom thumb turn lock unlocks when handle pushed down

Tags: repair, lock

I believe we have a thumb turn lock on our bathroom door. You twist the thumb lock bit from inside to lock the door and can see on the outside that the line is turned diagonally so can see it is locked.

However when you open the door from inside *or outside* when the door is locked, it unlocks itself!

Essentially it is pointless. Is it supposed to do this and does anyone know how to fix it please? I don't know what the lock was like when it was originally fitted as it was there before we moved into the house.

[image]

Comment: Unlocking automatically by turning the handle from the _inside_ seems like 100% proper operation. Unlocking by turning the _outside_ handle can be... awkward... if this is a bathroom door. Can you find any manufacturer or model info printed on the hardware anywhere?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I cannot find any information from just looking at it and do not feel confident I'm removing it to see if I can see any information inside the lock. We think that because our housemate keeps slamming the handle down when she walks in, that this has caused it, she has walked in on us in the bathroom many times and it is causing awkwardness lol

Comment: If you can provide pics of the top/bottom of the lever and the turn knob, someone will be able to ID how to remove the levers, then it's just 4 simple Phillips-head screws to take the handle off. _HOWEVER_, "flatmate" indicates A) you're renting, and B) you're in UK (perhaps Aus), so 1) You may want to contact the landlord to have him do the repair, and 2) you may not legally be allowed to make the repair on a property you don't own. If you're not confident and you're renting, call the property manager/owner and Bob's you uncle! ;)

Comment: I have an exterior door that requires the handle to be pushed up to engage the bolt, the turning the knob locks the bolt in position.  Could this be it?

Comment: Thank you, you are correct we are in UK and renting. I am new to this renting thing, I think that we will have to tell the landlord but because of the pandemic, it feels wrong to ask for assistance from him on this over such a small thing even though its causing problem so I may wait until it is safer in the world. Thank you kindly for your advice :)

Comment: Evil Elf - the handle doesn't move upwards unfortunately

Comment: Of course, if you can get all the flatmates to learn to knock first, that's an ideal situation, but there's no reason to not call the landlord in to get this fixed as soon as possible. Maybe schedule a time when you're all at work/school/at the pub/whatever so (s)he's there with none of you there.

Comment: Good idea! Thank you FreeMan for all you help and advice, it is greatly appreciated ☺️